# Largest prefix with given property

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Consider there is an array `a` - we need to find the largest prefix of a such that it is good.

The array `b` of length `m` is called good, if you can obtain a non-decreasing array `c` (c1 ≤ c2 ≤ ⋯ ≤ cm) from it, repeating the following operation m times (initially, select either the first or the last element of `b`, remove it from `b`, and append it to the end of the array `c`).

I could only brute force the solution but is there any effective algorithm?

Answer (score 2):

Prove (or at least convince yourself) that a good array cannot have a local minimum. That means that the good array must be unimodal (and a unimodal array is obviously good). In other words, the prefix you are after consists of a non-decreasing leg, followed by a non-increasing one (both could be empty of course).

Such prefix can be found in simple a linear scan.

I hope it is enough to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Simply saying, the array will be bad when array becames increasing after decreasing when traversing from backside else in any other condition it will be good array.

Eg

4 8 1 2 1
Here in this case array will be good when we exclude first 2 elements.Looking the eg in other way when we are traversing from backside.

1->2 increasing

2->1 decreasing

1->8 increasing---break.. exclude all elements before 8(including 8).